# SwipeRefreshLayout Swipe gesture Initially not working in Fragment

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Swipe gesture doesn't work at first. This happens when there is no item in the recyvlerview. Once a item is added and the fragement's onViewCreated Function is again called. SwipeRefreshLayout works fine even of the recyclerview is empty. The problems reappears on restart of the activity.

This issue is there on SavedFilesFragment ([LInk](https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver/blob/master/app/src/main/java/a/gautham/statusdownloader/Fragments/SavedFilesFragment.java))

Here is code

```
public class SavedFilesFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final List<Status> savedFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private FilesAdapter filesAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private TextView no_files_found;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved_files, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFiles);
        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayoutFiles);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        no_files_found = view.findViewById(R.id.no_files_found);

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), android.R.color.holo_orange_dark)
                , ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary),
                ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this::getFiles);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), Common.GRID_COUNT));

        getFiles();

    }

    private void getFiles()

        final File app_dir = new File(Common.APP_DIR);

        if (app_dir.exists() ||
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            no_files_found.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            new Thread(() -> {
                File[] savedFiles;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                    ) + File.separator + "status_saver");
                    savedFiles = f.listFiles();
                } else {
                    savedFiles = app_dir.listFiles();
                }
                savedFilesList.clear();

                if (savedFiles != null && savedFiles.length > 0) {

                    Arrays.sort(savedFiles);
                    for (File file : savedFiles) {
                        Status status = new Status(file, file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath());

                        savedFilesList.add(status);
                    }

                    handler.post(() -> {

                        filesAdapter = new FilesAdapter(savedFilesList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(filesAdapter);
                        filesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    });

                } else {

                    handler.post(() -> {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        no_files_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dir doest not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });

                }
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }).start();

        } else {
            no_files_found.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

I tried creating a Button to call the same function `getFiles()` but the Button too doesn't work the same way

Comment: Do you see refresh icon when you pull down for refreshing or nothing at all? Besides, do you left `getFiles` implementation empty intentionally? You shoul consider adding its implementation as well as of the xml where you implement swipe and refresh control.

Comment: No, the refresh Icon doesn't shows up.  `getFiles()`  is Implemented. It's a open source project and I have added the link in my Question.

Comment: Let me edit the question and add the getFiles() code too

Comment: I tried recreating the same fragment and transfered code little bit at a time. I found that `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), Common.GRID_COUNT));` adding this line causes the Issue. Can you explain how this causing the issue.